# Live Detection of scrollView position in panned view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, scrollview, swipe

I have a panned UIViewController at the initial launch that loads up two individual XIB views which the user can swipe to traverse through. I'd like to trigger code once the user swipes 2/3 across the total width (panned width of both views) but my detection isn't live.

Here's my code so far...

```
let vc0 = ViewController0(nibName: "ViewController0", bundle: nil)
let vc1 = ViewController1(nibName: "ViewController1", bundle: nil)

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.addChildViewController(vc0)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(vc0.view)
        vc0.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        var frame1 = vc1.view.frame
        frame1.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width
        vc1.view.frame = frame1


        self.addChildViewController(vc1)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(vc1.view)
        vc1.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 2, self.view.frame.size.height - 66)

        // This doesn't work
        scrollView.delegate = self


        // If the user user swipes 2/3 in (or it can be any other offset that's practical)
        if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > (self.view.frame.size.width*2)*(2/3)) {
             // Code I'd like to execute
             // ...
        }
 }
```

How is this possible with Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the delegate of the scroll view using

```
scrollView.delegate = self
```

and declare that your class implements `UIScrollViewDelegate`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate
```

Then implement `scrollViewDidScroll` which is called every time your scrollview's scrolling is changed.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   // If the user user swipes 2/3 in (or it can be any other offset that's practical)
   if (scrollView.contentOffset.x > (self.view.frame.size.width*2)/(2/3)) {
     // Code I'd like to execute
     // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Setting the delegate did not work. I have updated my code to show some insight on how my pan scrolling is working. Perhaps I'm doing it another way which conflicts with your solution?

Comment: I updated my answer, just add `UIScrollViewDelegate ` to your class declaration

Comment: You're awesome and saved me a lot of headache tonight. So that's how it works!!! Thank you so much for instructing me! :-)